# Можно ли будет связать Spring thymeleaf c JS, чтобы переменной внутри JS-файла присваивалось значение из БД?

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

ситуация такая:
Учусь делать сайт для дипломной работы, до этого имел небольшой опыт в языке java, и собираюсь реализовать его с помощью Spring Framework, начал разбираться с фронтэндом. Суть сайта - магазин чая.
Основная страница сайта будет состоять из "панелей" по одной для каждого вида напитка, нижняя ее часть показана тут[image: :]
При выборе размера напитка, цена автоматически изменяется(прописал логику в JS-файле), но цену я указал ТОЖЕ в нём, в будущем, я понимаю, что придется брать информацию о цене из БД(планирую использовать thymeleaf spring для этой цели).
Я понимаю, что таких "панелей" на странице будет много и если с HTML и CSS все, вроде, понятно, то с JS возникают проблемы:
Допустим, что панелей будет 30, для каждой панели используются свои кнопки, событие которых обрабатывается в JS файле, так вот:
Было бы не правильно создавать отдельный JS файл для каждой "панели", или именно так и нужно поступать?
Или в одном JS файле нужно создавать события для кнопок каждой панели, но это тоже кажется неправильным подходом?
И можно ли будет связать thymeleaf c JS, чтобы переменной внутри JS-файла присваивалось значение из БД? а затем оно выводилось в код HTML

Не судите строго, пожалуйста, у меня совсем нет опыта и я совершенно запутался в многообразии этих технологий, если что-нибудь будет непонятно, пишите, я постараюсь описать это подробнее
Спасибо!

Comment: Фронтенд и бэкенд, включая шаблонизатор thymeleaf - это две разных программы, написанные на разных языках, работающие на разных компьютерах в разное время. Единственный способ их взаимодействия - это передача данных через сеть по протоколу HTTP.

Comment: А можно спросить по поводу кнопок? Если на странице будет, к примеру, 30 кнопок, каждая из которых при нажатии берет СВОЮ цену и выводит на экран. Для всех этих кнопок нужен единый обработчик на JS, который будет определять какая именно кнопка была нажата и выводить для неё цену, я правильно понимаю?      Или не получится так сделать и для каждой кнопки нужен свой обработчик? Спасибо!